# I missed a job confirmation call from HR, called back and was told to wait for a callback but no feedback yet

Tags: interviewing, job-offer, human-resources, scheduling

So earlier today I got a missed call from the HR manager of a company where I had been interviewing for the past 2 weeks. I had successfully gone through 3 levels and was informed the the HR that I should expect a call by the end of the week (today) to finalize on my starting date and other particulars. Well today I missed that call accidentally and I made a call back to inform that I missed a call. I was then told that I would be given a call back but I haven't since heard anything yet. Should I be worried about this turn of events? I'm guessing probably HR got consumed in her work and probably forgot that she should call me back but it is all confusing given the anxiety level during such job seeking episodes. Any insights please?

UPDATE: So HR called me today and we discussed the job offer will be signing it this coming Tuesday. I was probably just too anxious

Comment: People miss calls all of the time. If you don't hear back from them today then call them on Monday.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unless there was an agreed-upon time for a pre-scheduled meeting, no one should expect that the called person would be available for a conversation over phone instantly. You did your part, informed them about missing the call. They have to take the next step. This is nothing unusual.

Don't panic and over-escalate. Wait for them to reach you, if they don't do that within a day (Say, Monday first half your time) - get in touch with them again. Not before that.

You appeared and cleared *three* rounds of interview - this indicates both the company and you would be interested in getting the deal finalized on a positive note. No need to worry as of now.